# Combine 1 bit inputs into single register appropriately

Tags: verilog, fpga, bit, parity

I am programming in verilog and I have a series of 1 bit inputs - say:

```
input SIGNALP,
input SIGNAL1,
input SIGNAL2,
input SIGNAL3,
input SIGNAL4,
input SIGNAL5,
input SIGNAL6,
input SIGNAL7
```

I then want to combine these bits into an 8 bit register, where the first bit is the parity bit (`SIGNALP`), the second bit is `SIGNAL1`, the second is `SIGNAL2`, etc. How can I do this? Adding all of these, for instance, wouldn't work, as it wouldn't recognize the place value of these. The reason I'm doing it this way is because parallel data is faster than serial data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to concatenate these bits into a new register

```
wire [0:7] my_new_register;
assign my_new_register = {SIGNALP, SIGNAL1, ... SIGNAL7}; // you fill in ...
```

You didn't specify how you wanted each pin to be mapped into the new signal, so you will have to adjust this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make it a single vector:

```
 input [7:0] SIGNAL;
```

If you want your code to look nicer when referring to the parity bit, you can use a parameter of the module to refer to it (short example):

```
module parallel(input [7:0] SIGNAL,
                ...);

  parameter PARITYBIT = 0;
  ...

  always @(*) begin
     p = SIGNAL[PARITYBIT];
     ...
```

Unfortunately, the rest of the range (ie, `[7:1]`) is a bit more tricky to reference cleanly, though you can use the `[b:+w]` syntax. But since you had just `SIGNAL1`, `SIGNAL2`, etc, you can now just use `SIGNAL[1]`, `SIGNAL[2]`, etc.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this - how does each bit in the `SIGNAL` vector get mapped to the appropriate pin where the single bit of data is at? Thank you for answering!

Comment: Yes, if you instantiate the module correctly. Before you had something like `parallel name(.SIGNAL7(x), .SIGNAL6(y) ...);`, now youll have `parallel name(.SIGNAL({x, y, ...});`